# Most efficient method in PostgreSQL / PostGIS to check if 1 million linestrings cross each other?

Tags: performance, postgresql, postgis

I have a million linestrings in a table's geometry field, 'geom'. I am trying to find linestrings that cross one another, so that I can delete them from the original table.
I have created a GIST spatial index on 'geom', and clustered the table on that index. Is there a more efficient way of doing this that does not require making a trillion (10^6 x 10^6) comparisons?

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN A.length >= B.length THEN A.gid ELSE B.gid END)
INTO lines_self_crossing
FROM lines AS A, lines AS B
WHERE ST_Crosses(A.geom, B.geom) = true
;
```

I am cleaning up the 'lines' table I generated using ST_ShortestLine between 400,000 parcels and 40,000 road linestrings. I have already removed lines that cross roads or parcels. The table contains the unique ID's from both the origin parcel and the road that it ends at.

EDIT 
This is the rewritten query, and explain analyze output:

```
explain analyze
SELECT (CASE WHEN A.length >= B.length THEN A.gid ELSE B.gid END)
INTO shortline_crosses_shortline2
FROM parcelstiug_roadciu1mwt_sl_noroadnoparcelcross AS A
JOIN parcelstiug_roadciu1mwt_sl_noroadnoparcelcross AS B
  ON ST_DWithin(A.geom, B.geom, 1) 
  AND ST_Crosses(A.geom, B.geom) = true
WHERE A.gid <> B.gid       
;
```

Output from explain analyze:

```
`    Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..4273300.12 rows=96 width=24) (actual time=6.111..1692272.505 rows=8363188 loops=1)
      ->  Seq Scan on parcelstiug_roadciu1mwt_sl_noroadnoparcelcross a  (cost=0.00..21795.31 rows=897431 width=76) (actual time=0.008..128.911 rows=897431 loops=1)
      ->  Index Scan using ptiugrciu1mwtslnrnpc_spindex on parcelstiug_roadciu1mwt_sl_noroadnoparcelcross b  (cost=0.29..4.73 rows=1 width=76) (actual time=0.806..1.881 rows=9 loops=897431)
            Index Cond: ((geom && st_expand(a.geom, 1::double precision)) AND (a.geom && geom))
            Filter: ((a.gid <> gid) AND (a.geom && st_expand(geom, 1::double precision)) AND _st_dwithin(a.geom, geom, 1::double precision) AND _st_crosses(a.geom, geom))
            Rows Removed by Filter: 74
    Total runtime: 1696618.617 ms`
```

EDIT2 The indices are defined as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX ptiugrciu1mwtslnrnpc_gid
  ON parcelstiug_roadciu1mwt_sl_noroadnoparcelcross
  USING btree
  (gid);

CREATE INDEX ptiugrciu1mwtslnrnpc_parceltayoid
  ON parcelstiug_roadciu1mwt_sl_noroadnoparcelcross
  USING btree
  (parcel_tayoid);

CREATE INDEX ptiugrciu1mwtslnrnpc_roadgid
  ON parcelstiug_roadciu1mwt_sl_noroadnoparcelcross
  USING btree
  (road_gid);

CREATE INDEX ptiugrciu1mwtslnrnpc_spindex
  ON parcelstiug_roadciu1mwt_sl_noroadnoparcelcross
  USING gist
  (geom);
ALTER TABLE parcelstiug_roadciu1mwt_sl_noroadnoparcelcross CLUSTER ON ptiugrciu1mwtslnrnpc_spindex;
```

EDIT3: Using ST_Intersects instead of ST_Crosses shortens the runtime to 343616 ms.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ST_DWithin` You will only compare with those close to you. And will use index. My tables are 500k rows took around 30 sec.

This is my example to find when a node is disconect to the road network, I compare end/begin nodes and check if intersect to another end/begin nodes.

So only compare against the one close to 1 meters. And not compare to itself.

I think the value `0.0001` depend on your projecttion but is easy to test using `ST_Distance`.

```
SELECT 
      f.id as node_id, 
      g.id as line_id,
      'start_node' as type
FROM ways_rto f 
JOIN ways_rto g
  on ST_DWithin(f.sp, g.geom, 0.0001)
 and ST_Intersects(f.sp, g.geom)
 and NOT ( f.sp_txt = g.sp_txt OR f.sp_txt = g.ep_txt)
WHERE f.id <> g.id
```

**UPDATE:** I make another test duplicating my data and time is 60 sec. The only difference I can see is I compare point with line.

[image]

EXPLAIN ANALYZE

```
"Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..10748875.97 rows=1083 width=8) (actual time=13913.424..60016.767 rows=136 loops=1)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on test_rto g  (cost=0.00..54344.94 rows=1379094 width=140) (actual time=0.298..196.095 rows=1379094 loops=1)"
"  ->  Index Scan using test_rto_sp_idx on test_rto f  (cost=0.00..7.74 rows=1 width=55) (actual time=0.041..0.041 rows=0 loops=1379094)"
"        Index Cond: ((sp && st_expand(g.geom, 0.0001::double precision)) AND (sp && g.geom))"
"        Filter: ((sp_txt <> g.sp_txt) AND (sp_txt <> g.ep_txt) AND (id <> g.id) AND (g.geom && st_expand(sp, 0.0001::double precision)) AND _st_dwithin(sp, g.geom, 0.0001::double precision) AND _st_intersects(sp, g.geom))"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 7"
"Total runtime: 60016.872 ms"
```

Comment: Thank you Juan Carlos, at 1/3 of a meter this does shave a few minutes off, 30 now compared to 33 before.

Comment: Can you share the `explain analyze` ? looks like you have something else wrong. `1M^2 = 1E12` and  `500k^2 is 2.5E11` so should only be 10 time harder? Can you try making a smaller table of 500k just for comparasion?

Comment: I double the size of my data and only need 60 sec, you have something else slowing that process. As you can see the index do most of the job

Comment: Please see the explain analyze that I have added into the original question.

Comment: Yes, I was about to suggest that. Can you try with ST_Intersect instead? Can you post how is defined your table with indexes?

Comment: I just read `ST_crosses` what I understand is even if touch one node will return true. And `1` maybe to big  did you calculate ST_Distance to test it? I told you that value depend on your projection in my case 0.0001 is 1 meter

Comment: I have added edits 2 and 3 to my question in response to your messages.

Comment: well looks like 6 mins is a great improvement.  You didnt reply regarding the distance 1. The only thing I dont understand in your plan, is the SEQ SCAN. Try the same but without the insert into, maybe that is other difference. Or remove the CASE... just for testing.